# Importing KDE global shortcuts defined by UUID?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I set up custom shortcuts using the Global Shortcuts GUI and want to transfer them to my other machines. When I export these shortcuts to a file, there are lines like:

```
{f7cae817-7e09-468e-b039-95c17c8a78fc}=Ctrl+Alt+T; Meta+Return
```

These are my keyboard shortcuts to open Konsole. However, when I look at `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` on my other machine, I see this:

```
{bfe68ec1-dbd0-467b-9978-edc4e342d7b0}=Ctrl+Alt+T,none,Run Konsole
```

So it appears that the action to launch Konsole does not have a name, but has a UUID that is machine-specific. Consequently, when I import my shortcuts file on another machine these shortcuts don't work. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: I've posted a link to your question [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a2295u/help_wanted_exporting_shortcuts_to_a_new_machine/) as well just in case. I don't know why KDE has such a complicated way of storing shortcuts.